# What is the basis for the default sigma value used by svmRadial in caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, caret, radial-basis

I am looking at the source code (I think) for the "svmRadial" function in the [caret package](http://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/svmRadial.R). It looks like the default sigma values are calculated by first using the kernlab package's "sigest" function -- which can be used to generate a range of possible sigma values. And then taking the mean of the sigest values EXCLUDING the second value in the vector of suggested sigmas. Why is this?

See line 8:

```
sigmas <- kernlab::sigest(as.matrix(x), na.action = na.omit, scaled = TRUE)
```

And then lines 10-11:

```
out <- expand.grid(sigma = mean(as.vector(sigmas[-2])),
                                         C = 2 ^((1:len) - 3))
```

(note: sigmas[-2]).

I also confirmed this by running my own models, one in which I rely on the defaults (i.e. specify only the method and don't set tuneGrid).

```
train(form = outcome ~ predictors,
      data = train_set,
      method = "svmRadial")
```

And one where I calculate sigma myself, recreating what I think is the default method (at least for calculating: sigma).

```
sigma_svm <-
  mean(kernlab::sigest(as.matrix(train_set)), scaled = TRUE))[-2]

train(form = outcome ~ predictors,
      data = train_set_ex,
      method = "svmRadial",
      tuneGrid = expand.grid(sigma = sigma_svm,
                               C = c(1)),
      trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV",
                                  number = 3))
```

And indeed when I do this I wind up with the same sigma value as with the default (i.e. "Tuning parameter 'sigma' was held constant at a value of 0.006038915" in both cases).

My question is why is the default method of svmRadial in caret to take the mean of the vector of the sigma values suggested by sigest EXCLUDING the second value in this vector ("sigmas[-2]")? This seems odd and very specific. I don't get it. Maybe I am misunderstanding something.